# Conditionally cancel swipe-scrolling on IE11

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, touch, internet-explorer-11

I have a big DIV (`#screenArena`) where I render several screens. In the image, assume each little square is the size of the screen. White squares have content, while black squares are empty.

The visible part of `screenArena` is the size of one square. I then scroll ScreenArena to sequentially show the screens as the user swipes.

[image]

To take advantage of hardware scrolling, that by the way really rocks, I use:

```
#screenArena {
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
    -ms-scroll-snap-points-y: snapInterval(0%, 100%);

    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-x: snapInterval(0%, 100%);
    scroll-snap-points-y: snapInterval(0%, 100%);

    overflow:auto;
}
```

This works as expected, so as the `screenArena` has many "squares" with different screens, the user swipes and the scroll snaps in each square.

The problem: Not all positions are valid, some are empty, so I'd like to cancel the scroll event at runtime if I decide it's an empty position.

With JQuery:

```
   $("#screenArena").scroll(function(scrollEvent) {

       if (CHECK_SQUARE_IS_EMPTY()) {
          window.console.log ("Scrolling prevented");
          var origEvent=scrollEvent.originalEvent;
          origEvent.preventDefault();
          origEvent.stopPropagation();
          return false;
       } else {
          window.console.log ("Scrolling permitted");
          return true;
       }
   });
```

However, this doesn't prevent the scrolling. Not `stopPropagation`, not `preventDefault`, neither returning `false`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a lot of things and found a very simple solution that works decently.

If during the scroll event I decide the square is empty, I just reset the `scrollTop` / `scrollLeft` to the original (initial) position inside the event:

```
$("#screenArena").scroll(function(scrollEvent) {

       if (CHECK_SQUARE_IS_EMPTY()) {
          window.console.log ("Scrolling prevented");
          if (SCROLLING_UP || SCROLLING_DOWN) this.scrollTop=ORIGINAL_SCROLL_TOP_POSITION;
          if (SCROLLING_LEFT || SCROLLING_RIGHT) this.scrollLeft=ORIGINAL_SCROLL_LEFT_POSITION;
       } else {
          window.console.log ("Scrolling permitted");
       }
   });
```